# Maintaining users in a Dovecut user database

Tags: bash, linux, email

I learn BASH scripting occasionally from time to time, now I am working on a simple bash script that serves to maintain [Dovecot](http://dovecot.org) user database. The general purpose of the script is able to list, add or delete user entries in the specified file. Please add some comments about the code - common mistake and etc. I want to learn more about code simplicity and avoiding bad habits.

```
#!/bin/bash

USERDB="/etc/dovecot/users"
MAILBOXMAP="/etc/postfix/virtual/virtual-mailbox-maps.cf"

## Add user function

add_user () {

# Reading username

while [[ -z "$USERNAME" ]]; do
    echo -n "Please enter username: "
    read "USERNAME"
done

# Reading domain name

while [[ -z "$DOMAIN" ]]; do
    echo -n "Please enter domain name: "
    read DOMAIN
done

# Reading password and generating hash with doveadm pw

while [[ -z "$PASSWORD" ]]; do
    echo -n "Please enter user password: "
    read "PASSWORD"
done

if [[ -n "$PASSWORD" ]]; then
    USERPASS="$(doveadm pw -p $PASSWORD -s SHA512-CRYPT)"
fi

# Adding provided credentials to Dovecot userdb

echo "Adding user credentials to userdb..."

echo "$USERNAME@$DOMAIN:$USERPASS:::" >> "$USERDB"

# Adding provided user@domain to postfix mailbox map

echo "Adding user credentials to postfix map..."

echo "$USERNAME@$DOMAIN $DOMAIN/$USERNAME" >> "$MAILBOXMAP"

# Hashing the map

if [[ -f "$MAILBOXMAP" ]]; then
     postmap hash://"$MAILBOXMAP"
     echo "Hashing map is done!"
else
     echo "Postfix map not exist or have been moved to another directory!"
     exit 1
fi
exit 0
}

## List all users function

list_users () {

if [[ -f "$USERDB" ]]; then
    awk -F: '/./'' {print $1} ' "$USERDB"
else
    echo "User database not exist or have been moved to another directory!"
    exit 1
fi
}

## Delete user function

delete_user () {
if [[ -n "$DELUSER" ]]; then
    sed -i "/^$DELUSER$/d" $USERDB $MAILBOXMAP && echo "User account have been  deleted!"
else
    echo "User not found!"
    exit 1
fi
}

case "$1" in
 add|-a)
    add_user
    ;;
 list|-l)
    list_users
    ;;
 delete|-d)
    shift
    deluser="$1"
    delete_user
    ;;
 *)
    echo "Unknown command"
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 3):

In this code:

> ```
> while [[ -z "$USERNAME" ]]; do
>     echo -n "Please enter username: "
>     read "USERNAME"
> done
> ```

What if the variable `USERNAME` is not empty when this code is reached?
For example, the environment might be *dirty* by misbehaving scripts,
and `USERNAME` might already be set to garbage, and the script will not prompt the user.

`echo -n` is not recommended because it's not portable. Use `printf` instead.

There's no need to quote `USERNAME` when reading into it.

The equivalent code, safer and better:

```
USERNAME=
while [[ -z "$USERNAME" ]]; do
    printf "Please enter username: "
    read USERNAME
done
```

Do similarly for the other loops too.

---

This will fail if `PASSWORD` contains spaces:

> ```
> USERPASS="$(doveadm pw -p $PASSWORD -s SHA512-CRYPT)"
> ```

To make it safe, quote it:

```
USERPASS="$(doveadm pw -p "$PASSWORD" -s SHA512-CRYPT)"
```

---

It would be better to indent the function bodies. For example:

```
list_users () {
    if [[ -f "$USERDB" ]]; then
        awk -F: '/./'' {print $1} ' "$USERDB"
    else
        echo "User database not exist or have been moved to another directory!"
        exit 1
    fi
}
```

This is especially helpful in the case of longer functions.

---

The quotes are strange and confusing in this `awk`:

> ```
>         awk -F: '/./'' {print $1} ' "$USERDB"
> ```

It would be better simply this way:

```
        awk -F: '/./ {print $1}' "$USERDB"
```

Comment: I mean any ideas about how to add feature "change user password" in script listed above?

Comment: Similar to what you did in `delete_user`, you could use `sed` to replace the line with the user to change. And I suppose you'd have to rehash the `$MAILBOXMAP` file, but I don't know dovecot, so this is really just a guess. If you need more details, it would be better to ask on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I can't understand how to replace a set of characters between delimeters for exact lines with sed... Check this line for example (this is the part from dovecot userdb):
`123@example.com:{SHA512-CRYPT}$6$0vthg.LubtSCxRRK$MdTKNQ2Vk8ZW3XQXNXStt9rfr6fNaXqPvZ0o9WJ8mW8y9ozE1pi8dYM8oQzwWa8ESGzEmJO6yT/tgi3ZEqAiE0:::`

How to replace the string starting with "{SHA512-CRYPT}" only for user "123@example.com" and not for user "abc@example.com" with sed?

p.s. The $MAILBOXMAP variable actually need only for Postfix.

Comment: Or we have a much simplier but ugly solution - change the whole line with username and password.

Comment: Such questions really belong on Stack Overflow, not this site.

Comment: Ok, i'll try ask there, thank you for help anyway!